# Issue when connecting to open shift via mysql workbench on Mac

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench, openshift, redhat

I am trying to connect to open shift with mysql workbench on an iMac. A colleague has shown me his setup on Windows which looks exactly as follows (other than the usernames / passwords changing)

[image]

However I keep running in to the following error and I have no idea how to fix it - I am 100% sure my password is ok, so don't really understand why it would say password yes.

[image]

Is there any special configuration differences needed between a Mac and PC setup?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This question has been double posted: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71443/issue-when-connecting-to-open-shift-via-mysql-workbench-on-mac

Answer (score 0):

It looks like adminM4B1nHl is connecting from 10.34.23.71 which might not work.  Check your MySQL security settings.  Sometimes admins can only connect from localhost (127.0.0.1).  You may have to grant the user access from any IP address.  Refer to MySQL docs on how to do that.